# Redirect logged information from one computer to a process in another?

Tags: sockets, logging, pipe, syslog

**My setup:** I have one computer running an application, `foo`, and logging information using rsyslog to a file on another remote machine. The remote machine is running a different application, `bar`. `bar` reads the logged files it has received and does some processing with this information, however, this is slow.

**What I'm trying to do:** I would like to pipe the information from `foo`'s log file into the process `bar` directly. I suppose I theoretically could alter `foo`'s source code to support something like this to even bypass rsyslog or writing to a file locally, but it is a massive enterprise-level software and would be a last resort.

Comment: why not listen on the rsyslog port yourself in bar (assuming there is no other need for rsyslogd on that machine)

Comment: I don't really get your question.. Why pipe the file directly into a file without rsyslog? You can do that with rsyslog too.. also, setting up a reliable system that continuously sends/receives logs takes much more effort, than just using an existing one.

But maybe I didn't really understand your question?

Comment: So with my current setup, it pipes the log info into a file. What I'm trying to do is not pipe it into a file, but into a process that I have running- say logProcessor.py